# Another "RecyclerView duplicating items" question

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, duplicates, android-edittext

I'm having this problem and spent hours exploring different solutions found here but couldn't figure it out. I have a RecyclerView with a RadioGroup (with two RadioButton) and an EditText. As expected, the text keeps getting duplicated on scroll and the "original" gets deleted. The same happens with the radio buttons. I've tried to save on another array backup the values when the view is recycled but couldn't solve the duplicating issue.

Here's my adapter

```
class ServicesCheckoutAdapter(var context: Context,
                              var servicesList: List<Service>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ServicesCheckoutAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var onRadioGroupClickListener: OnRadioGroupClickListener

    private lateinit var onTextChangedListener: OnTextChangedListener

    private lateinit var onServiceClickListener: OnServiceClickListener
    private var externalArray = mutableListOf<String>()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.services_list_item,
                parent, false)

        val viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)

        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

        view.setOnClickListener {

            if (onServiceClickListener != null) {
                onServiceClickListener.onServiceClick(view, servicesList[position].id, position)
            }
        }

        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return super.getItemId(position)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return super.getItemViewType(position)
    }

    interface OnServiceClickListener {
        fun onServiceClick(view: View, serviceId: Int, position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnServiceClickListener(listener: OnServiceClickListener)
    {
        onServiceClickListener = listener
    }

    interface OnRadioGroupClickListener {
        fun onRadioGroupClick(buttonId: Int, serviceId: Int, position: Int) {}
    }

    fun setOnRadioButtonClickListener(listener: OnRadioGroupClickListener) {
        onRadioGroupClickListener = listener
    }

    interface OnTextChangedListener{
        fun onTextChanged(position: Int, text: String)
    }

    fun setOnTextChangedListener(listener: OnTextChangedListener){
        onTextChangedListener = listener
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        Log.d("recycler", "lista: ${servicesList[position].serviceSolution}")

        holder.edtSolution.removeTextChangedListener(holder.watcher)

        holder.bind(context,
                servicesList[position].id,
                servicesList[position].name,
                servicesList[position].serviceSolved,
                servicesList[position].serviceSolution,
                onRadioGroupClickListener,
                onTextChangedListener,
                position)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return servicesList.size
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var radioGroup = itemView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroupService)
        val edtSolution = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextCheckoutDesc)
        var watcher: TextWatcher? = null


        fun bind(context: Context,
                 serviceId: Int,
                 serviceName: String,
                 serviceSolved: Boolean,
                 serviceSolution: String,
                 onRadioGroupClickListener: OnRadioGroupClickListener,
                 onTextChangedListener: OnTextChangedListener,
                 position: Int
        ) {

            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.serviceTitle)
                    .text = context.resources
                    .getString(R.string.service_title_comma, serviceName)

            itemView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroupService)
                    .setOnClickListener {
                        onRadioGroupClickListener
                                .onRadioGroupClick(
                                        (it as RadioGroup).checkedRadioButtonId, serviceId, adapterPosition)
                    }



            if (serviceSolved) {
                radioGroup.find<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtnYes).isChecked = true


                radioGroup.find<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtnNo).isChecked = false
            } else {

                radioGroup.find<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtnYes).isChecked = false


                radioGroup.find<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtnNo).isChecked = true
            }


            edtSolution.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    onTextChangedListener.onTextChanged(position, s.toString())

                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                }

            })

        }

    }
}
```

And here's the adapter initialization on the activity

```
serviceList = occurrence.services

        servicesAdapter = ServicesCheckoutAdapter(this, serviceList)

        recyclerViewServices.adapter = servicesAdapter
        recyclerViewServices.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        servicesAdapter.setOnRadioButtonClickListener(object : ServicesCheckoutAdapter.OnRadioGroupClickListener {

            override fun onRadioGroupClick(buttonId: Int, serviceId: Int, position: Int) {
                super.onRadioGroupClick(buttonId, serviceId, position)

                when (buttonId) {
                    R.id.radioBtnYes -> {
                        serviceList[position].serviceSolved = true
                        servicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }

                    R.id.radioBtnNo -> {
                        serviceList[position].serviceSolved = false
                        servicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        servicesAdapter.setOnTextChangedListener(object : ServicesCheckoutAdapter.OnTextChangedListener{
            override fun onTextChanged(position: Int, text: String) {
                serviceList[position].serviceSolution = text
            }

        })
```

Comment: How many items are you working with? If it's something small like 10 or 12, just use a normal Linear Layout. RecyclerView isn't meant to be used with input, only viewing. You'll have to manually save the state of each of the items and restore it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a dynamic list, but it probably wouldn't be larger than 20 items. And you're right, I think this is a job for a simple Linear Layout. Thanks, Ahmad Sattout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to use a ListView but the keyboard went crazy changing focus. Decided to keep the RecyclerView and since my dynamic list isn't so large, I used the

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

on the OnBindViewHolder() method and it solved my issue. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Can you elaborate why this worked?

Comment: Because with the setIsRecyclable set to false, I basically made the RecyclerView loose its function, so the views aren't recreated, thus the duplication never happening. It worked for me without any performance issues because my list was small.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView isn't usually made for Input views. As Android saves the input of a view depending on its ID, your RecyclerView has X number of views that all have the same ID, hence they all use the same state.

A solution to this would be saving your input state manually in `recycle` method, and restoring it in `bind` method.

So if you have 20 items, you have 20 states. Initially they are all empty or defaulted, and change when needed to save.

A more simpler approach would be using a LinearLayout or similar Layouts to accomplish your goal, but that depends on how many items you have and how many views that will contain.

You still need to be careful for the View ID part, though